# File Upload in Angular Form array

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to upload **pdf file** in **Form array** along with title.

I'm unable to add pdf file data in that form control.

On save I need to have title along with file data in their respective form controls.

Please help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Code available at
[Stackblitz click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nqd418?file=src/freq-docs/freq-docs.component.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML part -

> remove "formControlName"

```
<input type="file" (change)="upload($event,i)" accept=".pdf" class="form-control">
```

TS part -

```
upload(event: any, index: number): void {
    let fileName = event.target.files[0].name;
    this.docs.controls[index].patchValue({"file": fileName});
}
```

Comment: Just try to upload file first and then add text in title the form control value of file is changing

Comment: code updated, try.

Comment: You made my day! Thanks a lot man. Actually this was small part of my project and It worked exactly what I want.